# Running nUnit programmatically with Filter

Tags: .net, nunit

I'm trying use the nUnit API to launch tests programmatically, filtered by Fixture name.  Here's my code (where "fixtureType" is a .Net System.Type)

```
TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(assemblyPath);
RemoteTestRunner remoteTestRunner = new RemoteTestRunner();
remoteTestRunner.Load(testPackage);
TestFilter filter = new NameFilter(new TestName() { Name = fixtureType.FullName, FullName = fixtureType.FullName });
TestResult testResult = remoteTestRunner.Run(new NullListener(), filter, true, LoggingThreshold.All);
```

This doesn't seem to work - no tests are picked up.  Is there any easy way to execute only the tests belonging to a particular fixture?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the console runner? It is also easily controllable programmatically.

I did not find any public documentation about the `NameFilter` class. In the sources I found the following (see the unit tests for `NameFilter`):

```
TestFilter filter = new NameFilter();
filter.Add("Your.Test.Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

NameFilter does not simply work that way. See http://nunit.net/blogs/?p=23

Answer (score 0):

See also: SimpleNameFilter(string name)